# Clear posted values before returning the view

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I implemented a feature to automatically load the next record after finishing the current one.  On the server, I can get the next record and load it into the model fine.  The problem is, when I return the view, MVC favors the posted values from the *previous* record over the model values from the current record.

```
Public Function Update(model As UpdateModel) As ActionResult
    '... save changes to the model

    If model.LoadNext Then
        Dim nextRecord As UpdateModel = GetNextRecord()

        Return View(nextRecord)

    Else
        Return RedirectToAction("Index")
    End If
End Function
```

I've confirmed in the debugger that I am passing the nextRecord properly.  The view is reading the posted values (from the `Request` I guess?) instead of using the model.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior.  `Request.Form`, `Request.Params`, and `Request.QueryString` are all read only so I cannot clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call [ModelState.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.clear%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) before returning the view. Keep in mind [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is also an option if you don't want to break user navigation.

Comment: Thanks. I actually *want* to break user navigation in this case.  They're supposed to bookmark the landing page, not the individual record pages.